# What are the units for form widths and heights in VBA?

Tags: vba, forms, resize, pixel

I'm programming VBA for Word 2007.

I've created a UserForm which I need to resize with script.

I noticed that its **not pixels**

```
 Me.Width = pixelW   // form appears about 20% larger than the pixel width
```

And its **not twips** either

```
 Me.Width = (((1 / TwipsPerPixelX()) * pixelW)) / 1)  // form appears very small
```

So how are form widths and heights measured in Office 2007 VBA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When manipulating controls on forms through code the sizes are in twips by default (I believe if you change the form's ScaleMode property you can choose to use another unit).

Your conversion formula is wrong (it's easy to get wrong). Try this, wrapped in a function to avoid code duplication with potential for typos in every duplicate

```
Function nTwipsFromPixelsX(ByVal nPixels As Long) As Long
  nTwipsFromPixels = TwipsPerPixelX() * nPixels
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

When using VBA for Access, you usually express sizes in twips and/or centimeters, depending if you manage them from the user interface (centimeters) or from code (twips). As an example, you could set the column size for a combobox control in centimeters (by entering the corresponding values in the control's properties when the form is in design mode) or in twips (by updating these values from code while the form is open).

I guess this will also apply to VBA for Word. I'd advise you to write down both cmToTwips and TwipsToCm functions to make your measure conversions