# VBA to C# - Porting Userforms to Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, dimensions, vba

I am porting a Excel-VBA based app which uses Userforms over to a C# Winforms application.

How do I convert the Height and Width of the VBA-Userform to the same screen dimensions in the C#-Winforms application?  Is there a ratio that can use be used?

Currently the VBA-Userform has a dimension of 179.25 W x 245.25 H which is optimized for use on a quarter-VGA device.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351151/what-are-the-units-for-form-widths-and-heights-in-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using a [on-screen ruler](http://sites.google.com/site/rulerhelp/) that enabled me to measure the existing VBA userforms and then use the measurements (in pixels) to get the C# equivalent.