# What are the units for UserForm Left and Top in Word 2013 VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, units-of-measurement, office-2013, word-2013

What are the units for `UserForm.Left` and `UserForm.Top` in Word 2013 VBA?  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264175(v=office.14).aspx) doesn't say.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2351277/2877364) suggests they may be twips, but on my system, they are coming out as `0.75*pixels`.

That is, my screen is 1920x1200 but a userform moved to the lower-right corner has `Left`=1440=1920*0.75 and `Top`=900=1200*0.75.  The system has two monitors, each 1920x1200, screen resolution  96 DPI, and [`TwipsPerPixel[XY]`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/94927) both return 15.  Is it always three-quarters of a pixel, or is there some other system metric I need to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was staring me in the face, so here it is in case someone else benefits.  If you have a more robust answer, please post it!

The units were points, 72 per inch.  (72 = 96 dpi * 0.75.)  I converted pixels to points with

```
pts = Application.PixelsToPoints(pxls)
```

and then used `pts` for `Left` and `Top`.  `Width` and `Height` are also in points on my system.